# defaultvalue in inputText overwritten when disabled?

Tags: xpages

I don't know if this is a feature or a bug: In an inputText control, bound to an item of a notes document, the value is overwritten each time the xpage is reopened and saved by the defaultvalue when the inputText control is flagged as disabled:

```
                        <xp:inputText
                            value="#{fback.EmployeeIDCreator}" id="EmployeeIDCreator1"
                            defaultValue="#{javascript:sessionScope.meUser.EmployeeID}"
                            style="width:94px" disabled="true" />
```

I expected the same behaviour as in "normal" (=enabled) items:

- defaultValue assigned when document/xpage is new and the item is created,
- field value when xpage is reopened and reedited.

Is this the "wished" behaviour?

thx in advance, Uwe

Comment: is `fback` standard document data source, or your bean? isn't there another script overwriting the value?

Comment: fback is a standard document data source. I don't find any script which overwrites the value. The effect only occurs when disabled="true". sessionScope.meUser.EmployeeID is the employeeID of the current user, and this value is set in the EmployeeIDCreator item each time another user saves the xpage.

Comment: what version of Domino you use?

Comment: we use version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd run into this problem with fields that were marked 'readonly' as well. Set the style on the inputText to "display:none;" and have a separate control that displays the value. That way, your default value is saved in the field, but the user cannot edit it.

Comment: this is good workaround but it complicates the design. I think the cause is deep inside - disabled/readonly field does not submit its value on refresh, so not a part of model, so save substitutes its value with default. I think it won't be patched.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's a good work around for me - so I just made them again editible, plus unseen with  "display:none"

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be a bug. Reproducible on R9.0.1: disabled state of edit field resets its binded value to default value on save.

Answer (score 0):

We have a ticket open with HCL for this in 11.0.1 - CS0306235
The initial HCL response was "working as expected"
Subsequently someone in HCL raised this "Aha!" ticket because they disagreed - go vote for the "idea" - https://domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com/ideas/DDXP-I-980

In our case the workaround is to include .isNewNote() in an if statement as a condition of the default value.

```html
<xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (document1.isNewNote()){
    var addQText = getDbSettingsValueBlk('Configurable Additional Questions Text') ;
    if (addQText==''){
        // do nothing
    }else {
        return addQText;
    }
}}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
```